# slider revolution not showing html5 videos

Tags: html, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

im working on the avada theme on wordpress and i'm trying to make a revolution slider with an html5 video on it as a full screen layer. I'm working on localhost and using google chrome.

I put all the mp4, webm and ogv files with the correct path to the directory and the only thing i see in the slider is the background in black. I know the paths are correctly set because i put exactly the same on a fusion slider and it works perfectly. Can someone help me with this?

I'm a newbie in the foro so i don't know what should i put or not in order to help you guys to help me.

Comment: Same issue here. Is there at least some log file I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem.  It worked well with Chrome / Firefox but the background went plain black in IE / Safari, even though mp4/ogv/webm videos were all present and accessible.

I found out that it was an enocoding issue. I tried to convert the video with another program (After Effects) and both IE and Safari were able to play the video. Using "Any Video Converter" caused this issue.